# how to allow cross scripting for a specific site?

Tags: javascript, http, cross-domain, optimizely

I'm trying to test my website with Optimizely (a name of a tool allowing to create A/B tests etc). 
This tool tries to load my page inside an iframe and I get JS error: `blocked a frame with origin "...optimizely..." from accessing a frame with origin "...my site..." protocols domains and ports must match`.

I want to somehow allow optimizely to access my site and run the JS - what should I do?

1. I read I can add an http-header to allow such access, but I can't find if I can define it to allow for a specific site (I don't want to create a security breach)
2. I read something about `window.postMessage` but I guess I need to change code on both sides - and I won't be able to change Optimizely code

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) to allow other sites to download your content via AJAX (I hope it also works in your case). Here you have to use the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with a list of all domains your site wants to provide access to. Example:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example-social-network.com
```

More information about CORS, you will find on the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing